# dataTable selected row's not detected

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

i need to retrieve the selected row info in my dataTable but i'm getting error , i followed primefaces official docs but i can't understand where the problem is here's my code :

Xhtml page:

```
<p:dataTable id="groups" var="group" value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.groupsList}" rowKey="#{group.name}" selection="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedGroup}" selectionMode="single">

    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>

    <p:column id="column2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Group Name"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/group/#{group.name}.gif" />
        <h:outputText value="#{group.name}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="column3">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="text3" value=" Group Description "></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{group.description}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="See Permession " icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="permessionDlg.show()" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Modify Group" widgetVar="modifyGoupDlg" width="750" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">
    <br />
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="New Group :" />&nbsp;  
    <p:inputText id="updatedGroupName" value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedGroup.name}" required="true"></p:inputText>
    <br />
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="Group Description :" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p:editor id="updatedGroupDescription" value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedGroup.description}" width="600" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p:commandButton id="ValidateModif" value="Validate" actionListener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.modifyGoup}" onclick="modifyGoupDlg.hide()"></p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton id="CancelModif" value=" Cancel " onclick="modifyGoupDlg.hide()"></p:commandButton>

</p:dialog>
```

in my managed bean  ProjectAdminisrationMB i created an attribute 
    private Group selectedGroup; 
with getter and setter

Error :

```
Avertissement: /manage_Project_Groups.xhtml @96,133 value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedGroup.name}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedGroup' returned null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /manage_Project_Groups.xhtml @96,133 value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedGroup.name}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedGroup' returned null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:97)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
```

Comment: when does that error appear? when the page is loaded? or when you click the "See Permession" button?

Comment: it appears when i try to open the dialog modifyGroupDlg

Comment: `projectAdminisrationMB` is this correct? Could it perhaps be `projectAdministrationMB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first did you placed form tags? start with:

```
 <h:form id="form">
     //datatable
     //dialog
 </h:form>
```

Also you have oncomplete on is calling permessionDlg.show() but that isn't in your page (or you didn't posted the whole page) and you're not calling an update so your popup is never going to bu updated.

change:

```
<p:commandButton value="See Permession " icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="permessionDlg.show()" />
```

to

```
p:commandButton value="See Permession " update=":form:display" icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="modifyGoupDlg.show()" />
```

If this not solves the problem post your bean code and your complete page